# What should be the PMO's role in a Scrum Environment?

Tags: scrum, pmo

As we all know Scrum defines 3 roles Product Owner, Scrum Master and the Team.
Kanban chart is used to track progress, Velocity is used to measure SPI, Epic, Story and tasks are actually used to manage WBS.
I am wondering what different things should a Project Management Officer focus on in this set-up, other than providing already known metrics as reports?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### PMO's (Project Management Officer) role in a Scrum Environment

Project Management Officer can focus on the following:

1. In a large organization the Scrum Master will inevitably run up against organizational impediments. The PMO can be the escalation point for such issues and help overcome such impediments, if the Scrum Master has difficulty dealing with them.
2. Run scrum-of-scrum meetings with the Scrum Masters and Product Owners of multiple teams and resolve resource contention and priority issues.
3. Designate back-ups or step-in directly to cover for Scrum Masters who are on vacation or training.
4. Some stakeholders are difficult to pin down and don't take the time to see the end-of-sprint demos and provide timely feedback. PMOs may have to step-in to make this happen so that problems are not surfaced late in the cycle.
5. In general, be a champion/evangelist for Scrum/Agile process with senior management.

Answer (score 1):

None. Scrum has no role for project managers or a PMO.

Comment: So who should decide which team works with which product owner?

Comment: Hiring responsibility goes PO -> Dev Team -> SM  So, it's the PO's decision.

Comment: agree with Derek, When i am project manager in conventional Project Management environment then i would be switch to a Scrum Master in Scrum environment.

Comment: Product owner might be a more fitting position for a former PM, since he should decide on budget stuff. He's already aware of the organisation. A scrum master might want a fresh view to question it all. Also many conventional PMs are pure managers, right? I don't like the idea of a scrum master without dev experience. How are you going to tell a 50 year old dev to try test driven development? Do you have a feeling for when pair programming is good, when it might be bad? Not saying PM -> SM is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I believe their are still deliverables that need to be managed. PMO can determine what tools should be adopted with the help of the Scrum Team, I believe a backlog template can be created for stanardization, and to have a location that shares updated information on methodology and for individual to get introduced to what Agile and Scrum really is. Maybe even create check lists to determine when to use Waterfall methodology and when to use Agile and what type of other methodologies are under Agile Methodology.

I think there are many things that a PMO can be used for in a Scrum environment but I think it may not have many employees.